# Echarts Events When Finished Rendering

Tags: javascript, events, echarts

I am working with echarts and I would like to attach an event handler to do some things once my echarts instance has finished rendering but, can't seem to get it figured out.

From the [docs](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#events.finished) it seems like either finished or rendered should do the trick but its not working as expected.

```js
var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'))

chart.on('finished', () => {
 alert('finished event')
 console.log('finished event fired')
})

chart.on('rendered', () => {
 alert('rendered event')
 console.log('finished event fired')
})

chart.setOption({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line'
    }]
})
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

just use the new release, pls.
I use the 4.0.3, it's OK.

```js
var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'))

chart.on('finished', () => {
 alert('finished event')
 console.log('finished event fired')
})

chart.on('rendered', () => {
 alert('rendered event')
 console.log('finished event fired')
})

chart.setOption({
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line'
    }]
})
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.0.3/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez Echarts baseed on zrender, 1) [Come and see the source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/4.0.3/src/echarts.js#L1281): 'bindRenderedEvent' bind callback function on zr. 2) ['flush' function in zrender.js](https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/blob/4.0.3/src/zrender.js#L256) triggered the callback function. 3) ['_startloop' function](https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/blob/4.0.3/src/animation/Animation.js#L162) execute step function again and again before it isn`t running.    Sorry for my poor english, hope these clues can help you.